# Does vacillation imply intention or a mind? Can non-intelligent things vacillate?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, ambiguity

A friend and I are arguing about this.

Does vacillation imply a mind? Can a non-intelligent thing vacillate? In the context of video games my friend mentioned that his ping was vacillating. I argued that oscillate would be more appropriate in that context. Was his use of vacillate correct there?

I've only ever heard vacillate refer to a person unable to settle on a decision or course of action.

Comment: People vacillate, things oscillate.  If you want to anthropomorphize  then maybe you could say that a thing was vacillating.

Comment: Have you ever seen a squirrel crossing a road? If they don't vacillate, then neither do people.

Answer (score 2):

The definition for "vacillate" on [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacillate) is: "to repeatedly change your opinions or desires."

That would seem to me to imply that, in common usage and outside some sort of personification, the vacillating thing at least has opinions and desires. As for whether that requires a mind... ask on Philosophy Stack Exchange :).

Comment: I saw that definition but there are other definitions that seem to allow for inanimate objects

Comment: Dictionary.com's 3rd definition is "to oscillate or fluctuate."

TheFreeDictionary's second definition is "To change between one state and another; fluctuate"

Comment: I suppose you're right, but it seems to me that the connotative meaning of "vacillate" is different because of its connection to the definition I cited. If you allow words any reasonable flexibility of meaning, it is technically no more incorrect to say that something inanimate is vacillating than it is to say that a person's mind is oscillating between one choice and another, but the somewhat immaterial connotations of the former term and the more material connotations of the latter make the switch a bit awkward (or poetic, if that's what you're trying for).

Answer (score 2):

I would have no problem with that use of *vacillate*.

[Definition 1a at M-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacillate) states:

> to sway through lack of equilibrium

It is frequently used of people who cannot choose between possible options (indeed, other definitions do specifically mention "changing your opinion" and so forth), but it does not have to be used *only* for people; it makes perfect sense to include anything that is flipping back and forth, at unpredictable (but generally short) intervals, between 2 possible values.

*Vacillate*, *oscillate*, and *fluctuate* are listed as synonyms, but I would distinguish between them as follows:

> *Vacillate*: to switch back and forth rapidly but unpredictably between two values
>
> *Oscillate*: to move smoothly or regularly between two values
>
> *Fluctuate*: to move randomly within a range of values

In no case is it required that any of them refer to a person.

In your particular case, I would expect that *fluctuating* was the best word to choose, as I find it unlikely that a ping time restricted itself to only two values, but it's within the realm of possibility that it was vacillating instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would favor fluctuate to describe the ping in the computer game; that is, the ping moves in a given range rather than simply alternating two knowns.